# What datalink protocol is used in aircraft to ground station communication?

Tags: wireless, layer2

Laptops, mobile devices, and smart TVs communicate to access point via **WiFi**.

Wireless peripherals (mouse / keyboard) communicate to workstations via **Bluetooth**.

Mobile phones communicate to base stations via **GSM** / **UMTS** / **LTE** / **5G**.

Aircrafts communicate to ground stations via ____________ ?

Comment: That *very* much looks like an *certification, educational and homework* question which is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Zac67 no it's not. I composed that. I decided to make it an analogy so readers will understand better what I am asking.

Comment: good luck if you can prove that I copied that somewhere

Comment: Sorry, this is no trivia site (and there likely isn't a reasonable answer to your question). You'll need to check the [help/on-topic] for what questions are on topic here.

Comment: @Zac67 Sounds like you were just annoyed by my response. You could have close this question immediately but you only closed this after my reply. Anyway, I already got the answer, thanks to FrameHowitzer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variety of systems but generally High Frequency or Very High Frequency radio broadcasts.

https://www.aviationhunt.com/aircraft-communication-system/

Copied from that page:

Aircraft communications systems comprise the following:

Radio Communication

- HF System – For long-distance voice communications
- VHF System – For short-range voice communications Radio Management Panels
- SELCAL System – For selective calling using HF and VHF
- SATCOM System – For satellite communication
- ACARS – For datalink communication Interphone Communication
- Flight Interphone System – For internal cockpit communication and also with ground mechanics.
- Cabin Interphone System – For cabin crew or cabin crew/pilots communications.
- Service Interphone System – On ground only, for maintenance personnel only.
- Ground Crew Call System – To tell ground crew or flight crew there is a call.
- Passenger Address System – For passenger announcement from cockpit and cabin crew station.
- Audio Management System